# R user defined functions: new data frame name as function parameter

Tags: r, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions

I have run into a problem as I write user defined functions to manipulate data frames in R.  I want to write functions with 2 parameters: the name of the input data frame and the name of the data frame that will be created in the function.  Here is an example using the mtcars dataset:

```
subset_high_hp <- function(full_table, only_highHP) {
  only_highHP <<- full_table %>% 
    filter(hp > 200)

}

subset_high_hp(mtcars, mtcars_highhp)
```

subset_high_hp now creates a dataframe called only_highHP instead of the desired mtcars_highhp.  I know that this is a very basic question but I am new to R and really struggling to find the correct documentation.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: why not simply assign the output of the function to the name you want? (e.g. `only_highHP <- subset_high_hp(mtcars)`). I mean why take the name as a function parameter?
what is exactly the point of this?

Comment: This function will be called in another function indexing through lists of data frames, so I need to be able to simultaneously index through lists of new data frame names and perform a variety of other tasks in addition to subsetting, but if I constructed my code differently this would work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `assign` to do this trick:

```
subset_high_hp <- function(full_table, df_name) {
  sub_df <- full_table %>% 
    filter(hp > 200)

  assign(x = df_name, value = sub_df, envir = globalenv())
}

subset_high_hp(full_table = mtcars, df_name = "mtcars_highhp")
mtcars_highhp

   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
2 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
3 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
4 14.7   8  440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
5 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
6 15.8   8  351 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
7 15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```